# How to make a sprite follow your mouse cursor using pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a small game for a class project and am wondering how to make something follow my mouse cursor using pygame. I'm new to pygame so try to be understanding if it's obvious and I'm just stupid.

Comment: Calculate the x difference between the mouse cursor and your sprite's current location, and the y difference between the mouse cursor and your sprite's current location, and add a multiple of that distance (such as 0.2) to the sprite's current location.

Comment: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html

Comment: Also, if you need the sprite to move at a fixed speed, not move faster the further away it is, you need to use `angle = math.atan2(ydiff,xdiff)` to find out what angle it needs to move at, then move its x by `(speed*math.cos(angle))` and its y by `(speed*math.sin(angle))`. This will cause jitter if it's closer than one speed frame to the cursor, though, so you can check if it is by calculating if `(xdiff**2+ydiff**2)` is less than `speed**2` or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [line-by-line Chimp game tutorial](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/chimp/ChimpLineByLine.html) that shows you how to do this. Check out the `Fist` class and in particular, the `update` method:

```
class Fist(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """moves a clenched fist on the screen, following the mouse"""

    def update(self):
        "move the fist based on the mouse position"
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        self.rect.midtop = pos
        if self.punching:
            self.rect.move_ip(5, 10)
```

---

To play the game:

```
In [112]: import pygame.examples.chimp

In [113]: pygame.examples.chimp.main()
```

The code for the game is packaged with pygame.
To find out where the code is located using IPython:

```
In [114]: pygame.examples.chimp.main?
Type:       function
String Form:<function main at 0xb14dae4>
File:       /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygame/examples/chimp.py
```

Or to find where the code is located using the Python interpreter:

```
>>> import inspect

>>> inspect.getabsfile(pygame.examples.chimp.main)
Out[116]: '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygame/examples/chimp.py'
```